# Finding the equivalence classes of the given equivalence relation on $\Bbb Q$.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be a relation on $\Bbb Q$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
aRb \iff a^3 + b^2 + a^2 b = b^3 + a^2 + ab^2,
\end{equation*}
for all $a,b \in \Bbb Q$.

I've shown that this relation $R$ is a equivalence relation.
But, I got confused to determine the equivalence classes since it
was on $\Bbb Q$. For the integers part I've understood, but not yet for the fractions part. Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I don't see why this would be transitive. (-1,1)   and (1,0)  but no relation -1,0

Comment: by factoring, the three ways to get $aRb$  are $a=b ,  \; \;$   $a+b=0, \; \; $   $a+b=1, \; \; $

Comment: @WillJagy But in the question is to showing that the given relation is a equivalence relation and finding its classes. How?

Comment: Equivalence relations are transitive by definition. What you want is $\{b:  aRb\}$ for the NON-equivalence relation $R$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Since $R$ is not an equivalence relation, then its not have an equivalence classes, right? So, I answering the question by showing the counter-ex that $R$ is not an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{equation*}
aRb \iff a^3 + b^2 + a^2 b - (b^3 + a^2 + ab^2)=0\iff (a-b)(a+b)(a+b-1)=0
\end{equation*}
So set of all numbers related to a given number $a$ is $\{a,-a,1-a\}$. So for example, $\frac12R(-\frac12)$, $(-\frac12)R\frac32$ but $\frac12\not R\frac32$.

Comment: And hence, the relation is not a equivalence relation? Oh my bad. I didn''t see that there exists a counter-ex. Thanks!